# Jetpack compose LazyColumn inside LazyCloumn

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

In my homepage I have a lazycolumn which one of items is Horizontal pager. Inside each horizontal pager there are some pages that I need to have lazyColumn inside them too. and the error is that you are not allowed to use nested scrolling in same direction. How should I implement this ui?

```
@Composable
fun Home() {
    LazyColumn {
        item { }
        item { }
        item { }

        item {
            TabRow(selectedTabIndex =) {

            }
        }
        item {
            HorizontalPager(count =) { page ->
                
                when {
                    page == 0 -> {
                        LazyColumn {
                            items(list) {
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created an example. For me it works as expected. Please take a look

```
class ComposeActivity8 : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ComposeTutorialTheme {
                Home()
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun VItem(text: String) {
        Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(40.dp), text = text)
        Divider(color = Color.Black)
    }

    @Composable
    fun HItem(content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit) {
        Box {
            content()
            Divider(
                color = Color.Red, modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.CenterEnd)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .width(1.dp)
            )
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun CreateLazyColumn(pos: String, countItem: Int) {
        LazyColumn {
            items(count = countItem, itemContent = { index ->
                VItem("$pos.$index")
            })
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun Home() {
        LazyColumn {
            item { VItem("Vertical item 1") }
            item { VItem("Vertical item 2") }
            item { VItem("Vertical item 3") }
            item { VItem("Vertical item 4") }
            item {
                LazyRow(modifier = Modifier.height(150.dp)) {
                    item {
                        HItem {
                            CreateLazyColumn("Horizontal item 5.1", 6)
                        }
                    }
                    item {
                        HItem {
                            CreateLazyColumn("Horizontal item 5.2", 10)
                        }
                    }
                    item {
                        HItem {
                            Text(
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(40.dp),
                                text = "Horizontal item 5.3"
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    item {
                        HItem {
                            Text(
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(40.dp),
                                text = "Horizontal item 5.4"
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    item {
                        HItem {
                            CreateLazyColumn("Horizontal 5.5", 6)
                        }
                    }
                    item {
                        HItem {
                            Text(
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(40.dp),
                                text = "Horizontal item 5.6"
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    item {
                        HItem {
                            Text(
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(40.dp),
                                text = "Horizontal item 5.7"
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    item {
                        HItem {
                            Text(
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(40.dp),
                                text = "Horizontal item 5.8"
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
                Divider(color = Color.Black)
            }
            item { VItem("Vertical item 6") }
            item { VItem("Vertical item 7") }
            item { VItem("Vertical item 8") }
            item { VItem("Vertical item 9") }
            item { VItem("Vertical item 10") }
            item { VItem("Vertical item 11") }
            item { VItem("Vertical item 12") }
        }
    }
}
```

**VIDEO**

[image]

Comment: Just as a note, it only allowed to bypass error, but the reason why that error exists in the first place is still relevant: embedded LazyColumn essentially lost it's laziness and became wrap_content. To make an actual LazyColumn inside LazyColumn, you have to use CoordinatorLayout with custom behavior logic